# Rollup and Angular 5 JIT No NgModule metadata found

Tags: javascript, rollup, angular5, rollupjs

I am trying to setup JIT compilation with rollup but getting error:

> Uncaught Error: No NgModule metadata found for 'AppModule'.
>       at NgModuleResolver.resolve (ng_module_resolver.js:58)
>       at CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata (metadata_resolver.js:398)
>       at JitCompiler._loadModules (compiler.js:165)
>       at JitCompiler.*compileModuleAndComponents (compiler.js:125)
>       at JitCompiler.compileModuleAsync (compiler.js:91)
>       at PlatformRef*._bootstrapModuleWithZone (application_ref.js:390)
>       at PlatformRef_.bootstrapModule (application_ref.js:365)
>       at reflect.js:10
>       at reflect.js:10

Here is my setup rollup.conf:

```
import resolve from 'rollup-plugin-node-resolve';
import alias from 'rollup-plugin-alias';
import uglify from 'rollup-plugin-uglify'
const rxPaths = require('rxjs/_esm5/path-mapping');
import gzip from "rollup-plugin-gzip";
import html from 'rollup-plugin-html';

import { buildOptimizer } from '@angular-devkit/build-optimizer';

function angularBuildOptimizer() {
  return {
    name: 'angular-optimizer',
    transform: (content) => buildOptimizer({ content }).content,
  }
}

export default {
  input: 'js/src/main.js',
  output: {
    file: 'dist/client.js',
    format: 'iife'
  },
  name: 'MyModule',
  plugins: [
    alias(rxPaths()),
    resolve(),
    angularBuildOptimizer(),
    uglify(),
    gzip(),
    html({
      include: '**/*.html'
    })
  ]
};
```

> main-dev.ts

```
import './polyfill'; // <-- Moved polyfill import here. This has to be loaded before Angular

import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';


platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

> poufill.ts:

```
import "reflect-metadata/Reflect"
// import "rxjs/Rx"
// import "zone.js/dist/zone.js"
import "ts-helpers"

import "@angular/common"
import "@angular/core"
import "@angular/http"
import "@angular/platform-browser"
import "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic"
import "@angular/router"

import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
import 'core-js/es6/object';
import 'core-js/es6/function';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
import 'core-js/es6/number';
import 'core-js/es6/math';
import 'core-js/es6/string';
import 'core-js/es6/date';
import 'core-js/es6/array';
import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
import 'core-js/es6/map';
import 'core-js/es6/set';
import 'core-js/es6/reflect';

import 'core-js/es7/reflect';
// import 'zone.js/dist/zone';
```

> And here is app.module.ts:

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';


import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [BrowserModule],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Anybody know what can be wrong here?